# Rails: record expected, got false when associating record on after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have the following on the booking model

```
belongs_to :tour, optional: true

after_create_commit :add_to_tour

  def add_to_tour
    tour = Tour.where(experience: experience, time: time).first_or_create
    tour.bookings <<! self
  end
```

(added bangs to debug). Then I have this code on a method:

```
  booking = Booking.home_guide.where(pipedrive_deal_id: params['id']).first_or_initialize

    if booking.update!(
        some params
      )
```

this code fails with the following error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Booking(#71120) expected, got false which is an instance of FalseClass(#5700))
```

The booking is committed on the db, otherwise the callback would not fire. Why am I getting false? do I have to reload the booking somehow?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
array = []
array <<! 'Some object'
# => [false]
```

Because

```
!'Some object'
# => false
```

`!` is not debug. It is "not" operator

Comment: Additional context: There are both methods `update` and `update!` and the one with the `!` raises an exception if the update was not successful. But there is only `<<`. A method named `<<!` is simply not defined on ActiveRecord associations instead Ruby interprets that as `tour.bookings << !self`

Comment: got it. that was my bad.